# Laravel Eloquent Model Relationship with Condition in Relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

Hello Laravel Enthusiasts,

I have tables for Users, **Roles** and **Roles_User**

**Role** : `id`, `role_name`

**Roles_User** : `id`, `role_id`, `user_id`

in my Controller I have this

```
$users = User::all();
return view('admin.users.index', compact('users'));
```

How can I can display in my view all the users that has a role name with 'admin' or 'member'

Please help me build my Model and View.

Thank you

Comment: your question needs more clarity. ask a specific problem with desired result. share what have you tried so far. no one gonna code for you the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack Overflow is not a coding service, you will need to build your view. [Read here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#introduction).

As For the query, its simple:

```
 $users = User::query()
              ->join('role_user', 'role_user.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
              ->join('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'role_user.role_id')
              ->whereIn('roles.role_name', ['admin', 'member'])
              ->get();
```

If you have your relationships set up in your models, you can do the following:

```
$users = User::whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
             $query->whereIn('role_name', ['admin', 'member']);
         })->get();
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not mean about building the view. I can do it but I just do not know how the eloquent query to use in my model. Thank you very much